# IOS Image download

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Для загрузки изображений использую `AlamofireImage~>4.0`. Проблема на страницы с TableViewController где происходит вывод постов. Загружаются очень долго. И они в перемешку загружается. Например загрузилась одно фото до загрузки третьего фото он может выйти вместо него пока не загрузиться третье.

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этой статье есть примеры с решением проблемы:

https://habr.com/ru/post/320152/

Цитата:

> мы можем, когда приходят наши imageData из сети, проверить URL,
>   который вызвал загрузку этих данных, url и сравнить его с тем, который
>   пользователь хочет иметь в этой ячейки в данный момент, imageURL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/450113)

Comment: Добавил решение из источника.